# adding API to android sdk

Tags: android, api, sdk

I have downloaded android APIs and I've copied one of them to this path

```
H:\Android\android-sdk\platforms\api
```

But again in SDK none of APIs wasn't installed.

Comment: Did you install the api using the sdk

Comment: Please contact the vendor of the SDK about your support options. What you ask about should be obviously covered by the documentation it comes with. Contact support if you have problems to locate the resources to work through to get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe sdk is what is suppose to be used to install the API you should not be copying it.

follow:

You can launch the SDK Manager in one of the following ways:

From Eclipse (with ADT), select Window > Android SDK Manager.
On Windows, double-click the SDK Manager.exe file at the root of the Android SDK directory.
On Mac or Linux, open a terminal and navigate to the tools/ directory in the Android SDK, then execute android sdk.
You can select which packages you want to download by toggling the checkboxes on the left, then click Install to install the selected packages.

The link below will give you more pointers.
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html

Comment: yeah I downloaded from SDK manager it self now it's working nicely Thank U

Comment: anytime. im here to help

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Android SDK Manager to download the APIs for Android. Check this:

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html